# how to solve this equation for integers n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

If we have a sequence defined to be $(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+4}$ for all integers n negative and positive, how do we solve for $(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+4} = c$ in order to find the $n$ for a constant $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $n$ is even, $n=2m$ you have

$$(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+4} = \frac{2m}{2m+4} =\frac{m}{m+2}=c\iff m=\frac{2c}{1-c}.$$ So, you have solution iff $\frac{2c}{1-c}\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Proceed in a similar way assuming $n$ is odd.

**Edit**

If $n$ is odd, $n=2m+1$ you have

$$(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+4} = -\frac{2m+1}{2m+5} = c\iff m=-\frac{1+5c}{2+2c}.$$ So, you have solution iff $\frac{1+5c}{2+2c}\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: what about if n is odd but also n/(n+4) is negative? Is that just a special case that we have to sift through for n = -1,-3?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply solve two equations, both $$\frac{n}{n+4}=c$$ and $$-1\cdot \frac{n}{n+4}=c$$

and see if any of the two solutions is correct.

In theory, that means you first say "OK, if $n$ is even, what equation does it need to satisfy?", and then do the same for odd $n$.

---

Of course, you won't always get a solution. Right off the bat, if $c$ is irrational, there is obviously no solution, and there are plenty of other examples.

Comment: I think this is what i thought of upon seeing the problem. what if n doesn't turn out to be even, is it not a solution then by contradiction?

Comment: @gebra Yup. For example, if $c=\frac{1}{5}$, then there is no solution. This is because if $n$ is even, then it must be equal to $3$ for the equation to hold (which is not an even number), and if it is odd, then it must be equal to $-\frac23$ which is not an integer. So the equation has no solution for $c=\frac15$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{i\pi n} = c(1+\frac{4}{n})$

But magnitude is $1$ so $n$ must be integer and RHS is real so $n = 2$, $c = \frac{1}{3}$, $n = 4$, $c=\frac{1}{2}$...  $n = 2z$, $c=\frac{z}{z+2}$

Or $n = 2z+1$ and $\frac{-2z-1}{2z+1+4} = c = -\frac{2z+1}{2z+5}$

for integers $z$